# Are objects passed by value over Java threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, memory-management

Consider the following:

```
public class Capture extends Thread {
    private byte[] data;

    public Capture(byte[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something with the data byte array
    }
}
```

Would the `data` argument in the constructor be passed as reference to the new Java thread or would the object be re-instantiated, thus duplicating the memory?

Comment: This question is specifically regarding threads, not whether java is by reference or value...

Comment: Threads make no difference to the pass-by-whatever semantics of a language.

Comment: good job you answered the question